# Нужна ли запятая? 5

Tags: пунктуация

Новые газораспределительные системы экономически целесообразно создавать преимущественно с подачей потребителям среднего давления газа (0,3–0,6 МПа), с последующим его редуцированием до требуемых значений домовыми газовыми регуляторами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это деловой стиль, то желательно без авторских уточнений и пояснений. Запятая не нужна, это не оборот.

Comment: Спасибо большое!